# Exercise on Linear Bounded Functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

For an exercise, I need to prove that a functional is a bounded linear functional. The exercise is concretely posed as

Let $C([- \pi, \pi])$ be the Banach space of continuous functions on the interval $[- \pi, \pi]$ equipped with the usual norm $\left\| f \right\|_{\infty} = \max_{t \in [-\pi , \pi]} |f(t)|$. Let $g \in L^1([- \pi, \pi])$ be arbitrary and define therewith the functional $\varphi_g : C([- \pi, \pi]) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ by

$\varphi_g(f) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(t) g(t) dt \text{\quad } f \in C([-\pi, \pi])$

1. Show that $\varphi_g$ belongs to the dual space of $C([-\pi, \pi])$, i.e. show that $\varphi_g$ is a bounded, linear functional on $C([-\pi, \pi])$
2. What is the norm $\left\| \varphi_g \right\|$ of this functional?

Remark : Recall that $L^1([-\pi, \pi])$ is the Banach space of functions on $[-\pi, \pi]$ for which $\left\| f \right\|_1 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} |f(t)| dt < \infty$.

**My thoughts so far :**

1. I would argue that it is easy to see that $\varphi_g$ is linear since the integral itself is linear w.r.t. the argument. Hence, I would skip any explicit proof here. Further, to show boundedness, we have
   $\left\| \varphi_g(f) \right\|_{1} = \left\| \varphi_g \cdot f \right\|_{1} \leq \left\| \varphi_g \right\|_{1} \cdot \left\| f \right\|_{1}$. With $\left\| \varphi_g \right\|_{1} < \infty$ as per the statement in the Remark and with $\left\| f \right\|_{1} < \infty$ as per definition of the norm $\left\| . \right\|_{1}$, we consequently have that $\left\| \varphi_g \right\|_{1} < \infty$. This proves the statement.
2. ?

I would like to know whether the explanation in 1. is sufficient for the proof. Further, I am currently stuck with the norm in 2.

Any help is very much appreciated! :-)

Comment: What is $\mathcal C$? Why are you writing $\|\phi_g(f)\|_{L^{1}}$?

Comment: C is the banach space of continuous functions. Thanks for the notice, $L^1$ is not necessary to write, I have edited it just now :-)

Comment: Your definitions make no sense. $\int fg $ is a number, not a function.

Comment: There was a typo, yes $\int fg$ is a number, but I am interested in the operator norm $\left\| \varphi_g \right\|_1$

Comment: The fact that $\|\phi_g\|=\|g\|$ is part of Riesz Representation Theorem on the dual of $C[-1,1]$. You can find a  proof in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: Just to understand, you think my answer to 1. is correct and suffices as such? 
And w.r.t. 2. , I am not very much familiar with Riesz. Do you refer to Theorem 6.16 in Rudins RCA? (Complex Measures p. 127)

Comment: Your answer to 1) is not correct. You have misunderstood the definition of $\phi_g$.

Comment: Okay, so can you elaborate a bit further? Really appreciate the help!

Comment: The value of the functional $\varphi_g(f)$ is a number. You should notice that $|\varphi_g(f)|=|\int f(x)g(x)\,dx|\le  \|f\|\, \|g\|_1.$ Thus $\|\varphi_g\|\le \|g\|_1.$ The fact that actually $\|\varphi_g\|=\|g\|_1$ is nontrivial.

Comment: Thanks, RyszardSzwarc . I have pursued a solution using Riesz-Representation after catching up. As @geetha290km mentioned, I found a suitable proof in Rudin's RCA :-)